# Using Bootstrap only for the responsive feature and deleting other files

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to use bootstrap for responsive layout only, so I do not need to take all the bootstrap documents to my workspace folder. I want to know what file should be removed and what should stay?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the `bootstrap-grid.css` or `bootstrap-grid.min.css` this includes only the grid system which you can use for responsive, for more refer the bootstrap link

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files

hope this may help you.

Comment: happy to help, happy coding;-)